# Why is my Apache server not finding these PHP classes and files?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, permissions, themes

My Apache server is throwing errors of missing files and classes, even though they should be there.

I have a WordPress 6.0.2 installation running on PHP 7.4.32. The theme I am using is [Mies from Pixelgrade](https://pixelgrade.com/themes/portfolio/mies/), v1.9.4. (latest), and that was working until not long ago. I have set the permissions for the theme temporarily to 777, but still get the following permissions / not found errors thrown (actual domain name omitted for security reasons):

```
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922334 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24529:tid 139913208944384] [client 109.15.118.64:48788] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WPGradeOptions' not found in /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-content/themes/mies/wpgrade-core/bootstrap.php:36, referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922338 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922341 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-content/themes/mies/functions.php(39): require_once(), referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922351 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-settings.php(566): include('/var/www/vhosts...'), referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922355 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-config.php(167): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...'), referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922358 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...'), referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922361 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #4 /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...'), referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922365 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #5 /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-admin/update-core.php(10): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...'), referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922368 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: #6 {main}, referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:06.922371 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr:  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-content/themes/mies/wpgrade-core/bootstrap.php on line 36, referer: https://<my-domain>.de/wp-admin/index.php
[Tue Oct 11 15:18:09.509350 2022] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: scandir(/var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-content/themes/mies/wpgrade-core/classes): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>.de/httpsdocs/wp-content/themes/mies/wpgrade-core/wpgrade.php on line 596, referer: https://<my-domain>.de/baustelle-kindertagesstaette/
```

I've run out of ideas of what could be going wrong. Any leads on where I should look to troubleshoot the errors?

**Edit**
This is how the `bootstrap.php` file looks like around line 36 (the last one):

```
<?php

#
# This file performs initial environment setup.
#

// ensure EXT is defined
if ( ! defined( 'EXT' ) ) {
    define( 'EXT', '.php' );
}

do_action('before_wpgrade_core');

$basepath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

//require $basepath . 'wpgrade' . EXT;
get_template_part( 'wpgrade-core/wpgrade' );

// Dynamically load in all classes
// -------------------------------

# Loading convention: if it's a PHP file it's loaded, the shorter the path
# the higher the priority

$classpath = $basepath . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
wpgrade::require_all( $classpath );

// Setup Option Drivers
// --------------------

if ( wpgrade::confoption('wpml_separate_options', false ) ) {
    $wpgrade_redux = new wpGrade_Redux();
}

// the handler is the main object responsible for managing the drivers
wpgrade::options_handler( new WPGradeOptions() );
```

Comment: That `<my-domain>` looks rather suspicious. Why not search your code for this and replace it with the actual domain you're using?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I redacted the domain name for security reasons. In the logs it shows the correct path.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, that makes sense. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for looking into this. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the hosting provider made a bunch of silent updates to the production server. We had to revert back to PHP FPM as the machine was throwing a bunch of random errors (this was my hunch all along, something virtually undebuggable). Doing this made all the issues go away, and the site came back online with just a few tweaks to be made.

Comment: Good to hear that it all works again.